# cannot convert from ‘QString’ to ‘LPCWSTR’ in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, filesystems

I am working on an app where I need to display the file system format of the SD card. Since I couldnt find any Qt API’s for it, I choose a windows API **GetVolumeInformation** and did it as follows:

```
TCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
   TCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
   DWORD serialNumber = 0;
   DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;
   DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;

   LPCWSTR path = deviceData->m_strPath;

   if (GetVolumeInformation(
       path,
       volumeName,
       ARRAYSIZE(volumeName),
       &serialNumber,
       &maxComponentLen,
       &fileSystemFlags,
       fileSystemName,
       ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))
       {
                 qDebug()<<fileSystemName[0];
                 qDebug()<<fileSystemName[1];
                 qDebug()<<fileSystemName[2];
                 qDebug()<<fileSystemName[3];
                 qDebug()<<fileSystemName[4];
       }
```

**path** indicates the SD card path and when I run the app, it throws the following error:
“cannot convert from ‘QString’ to ‘LPCWSTR’”. Where am i making a mistake??? Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
LPCWSTR path = deviceData->m_strPath.utf16();
```

Comment: Thanks brother. My output now displays 70 65 84 51 50. I want it in a string format which I want to display. Could you please help? :)

Comment: How about just qDebug()<<fileSystemName; ?

Comment: @Gojira: You already got the string. "70 65 84 51 50" is "FAT32" in unicode. Use `QString::fromUtf16(fileSystemName)` to convert it to a `QString`.

Comment: Thanks hpsMouse and Pukku :)